# CKEditor5Field not displaying correctly in read-only mode for restricted user roles in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, ckeditor5

I'm encountering an issue with the CKEditor5Field in Django Admin when it's set to read-only mode for users with restricted roles. Specifically, when I log in with a user role that has write permissions, the CKEditor5Field works perfectly and displays the formatted text as expected. However, when I log in with a user role that only has read permissions, the CKEditor5Field does not render the HTML content properly. Instead, it displays the raw HTML tags without any formatting.

models.py

```
class SalesInfo(models.Model):
    feature_id = models.OneToOneField(
        FeatureFilm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, editable=False
    )
    ...

    sales_info = CKEditor5Field(
        verbose_name="Vertriebs Notizen", config_name="extends", null=True, blank=True
    )
...
```

admin.py

```
class SalesInfoSetInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    raw_id_fields = [
        "feature_id",
        "tv_movie_id",
        "tv_serie_season_id",
        "special_project_id",
    ]
    read_only_fields = [
        "feature_id",
        "tv_movie_id",
        "tv_serie_season_id",
        "special_project_id",
    ]
    model = SalesInfo
    exclude = ["is_sound_restoration_offer"]
    classes = ["collapse"]
    extra = 1  # 1 is here ok
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {"widget": Textarea(attrs={"rows": 12, "cols": 150})},
    }
```

I have also confirmed that I have correctly configured the CKEditor5 static files.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in understanding why the CKEditor5Field does not properly render the HTML content when set to read-only mode for users with restricted roles in Django Admin. If you have any suggestions or insights, please let me know.

Thank you for your help in advance.